# LINQ Join and Sum Query returns duplicate Results

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, group-by

I am running this query in LINQ which joins tables and returns the sum of sales per District ID.

```
var resultsalescity = (from so in _companysales
                    join en in _entity
                    on so.Id equals en.Id
                    group so by so.Id into totaledorders
                    from tot in totaledorders
                    join ad in _address
                    on tot.Id equals ad.EntityId
                    select new Salescities {
                        Totaledvalue = totaledorders.Sum(s = >s.TotalCost),
                        District = ad.DistrictId.ToString(),
                    }).ToList();

 return resultsalescity;
```

I get duplicates values returns:

```
[{"totaledvalue":3855.00,"district":"568"},{"totaledvalue":3855.00,"district":"568"}}
.....
```

How can I drop the duplicates on the district ID to return only one value for each district?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I'm getting 4 duplicates District ID in results with different sales values**

It's correct. Because It's grouped by Id. The actual result of 4 duplicates District ID would be different `_companysales.Id`. So you might be looking for something like this

```
var groupedByIdAndDistrictData = (from so in _companysalesRepo.QueryNoTracking
                                    join en in _entityRepo.QueryNoTracking on so.PharmacyId equals en.Id
                                    join ad in _addressRepo.QueryNoTracking on so.PharmacyId equals ad.EntityId

                                    group so by new {
                                        so.Id,
                                        ad.DistrictId
                                    }
                                    into totaledeorders

                                    select new Salescities {
                                        Totaledvalue = totaledeorders.Sum(s = >s.TotalCost),
                                        District = totaledeorders.Key.DistrictId.ToString()
                                    }).ToList();

var resultsalescity = groupedByIdAndDistrictData.GroupBy(p = >p.District)
                                    .Select(g = >new Salescities {
                                        Totaledvalue = g.Sum(s = >s.Totaledvalue),
                                        District = g.Key
                                    }).ToList();

return resultsalescity;
```

Comment: Hi Phuong thanks for your help! I think i dint explain myself right. At my final query results... I don't mind the ID of my stores... I just want to have to sum of sales for each District ID without duplicates.

Comment: yes, that query seems fine to me also?? I remove it but I'm getting 4 duplicates District ID in results with different sales values...

Comment: **I'm getting 4 duplicates District ID in results with different sales values** It's correct. Because if you use *The second query*, It's grouped by `Id, District`, The actual result of **4 duplicates District ID** would be different `_companysales.Id`. So you should use *The 3rd query*. Do you understand?

Comment: message":"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.","isError":true,"detail":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208610/discussion-between-simon-gis-and-phong).